# Jade: подключение разных стилей и скриптов в зависимости от страницы

Tags: javascript, html, jade, pug

Допустим, нас есть шаблон `base.jade`, где описан `head`, и от него наследуются макеты уже конкретных страниц. Однако, в зависимости от страницы, нам нужны разные подключения css-файлов и javascript-файлов. Как этого можно добиться?

**base.jade**

```
doctype html
html

    block head
    head 
        - var pageTitle = pageTitle || 'Имя страницы по умолчанию'
        title #{pageTitle}
        meta(charset='UTF-8')
        meta(name='viewport', content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0')

        // === css
        // допустим, этот стилевой файл должен быть на каждой странице
        link(href='/css/crossbrowser.css', rel='stylesheet')
        // далее в шаблонах-наследниках добавляются подключения стилей для конкретных страниц

        // js
        script(src="/js/common.js") // допустим, этот скрипт должен быть подключен на каждоый странице
        // далее в шаблонах-наследниках добавляются подключения скриптов для конкретных страниц


    body
```

Comment: https://pugjs.org/language/inheritance.html#block-append-prepend - вы читали документацию?

Comment: Эту - нет. Благодарю за источник.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В каждую вьюху вставляете нужные стили и JS таким образом:

```
link(rel='stylesheet' property='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='/css/style.css')
```

Атрибут `property='stylesheet'` позволяет загружать CSS в любой части документа. И это совершенно валидно.